# AJAX call is not reaching Servlet

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to make a simple textbox which initiate a suggestive feedback based on the characters entered by the user. I am trying to fetch a JSON object from a Servlet but my AJAX call is somehow not reaching the servlet. On checking the status of AJAX request using this.status I am getting error code 404. Can anyone suggest me a solution:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here's my servlet: FetchServ.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        Connection con;
        ResultSet rs;
        java.sql.PreparedStatement pst;

        String ch = request.getParameter("q");
        String data;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();

        response.setContentType("application/JSON");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("drivers registered");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(con_url, userID, password);
            System.out.println("connection created");
            pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM candidates where FirstName LIKE ?");
            pst.setString(1, ch + "%");
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("query executed");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                data = rs.getString("FirstName");
                list.add(data);
            }
        String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }   
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

the jsp code:

```
    <script>
function suggest(str){
    if(str.length == 0){
        return;
    }else{
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            document.getElementById("sugg").innerHTML = this.status;
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                //var res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("sugg").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }

        };
        try{
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "com.test.java/FetchServ", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }catch(e)
        {
            alert("unable to connect ");
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Search:<input type="text" onkeyup = "suggest(this.value)">
</form>
<p id = "sugg"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the result I am getting:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
     <display-name>ACtxtbox</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FetchServ</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.java/FetchServ</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FetchServ</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/FetchServ</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What do the browser debugging tools tell you?

Comment: I have tried your code and it's working perfectly

Comment: dont use default package try to give some meaningful package and use it in your web.xml

Comment: @stdunbar here's what Chrome Debugger says :
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/ACtxtbox/src/com.test.java/FetchServ.java
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: @SanjayPatel are you saying that the AJAX call is returning the suggestions from the back end ???

Comment: I have returned 'hello' from servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your **Web.xml** entries are not proper, check the url which you are using in urlbar and the form submitted using `xmlhttp.open("GET", "fetch", true);` you can debugg the actual url passed as a request to the server by opening `developer tools` and navigating to the `network tab` it will look something like below.[image]

also your `<servlet-class>ACtxtbox/FetchServ</servlet-class>` is not correct, it should be with package path like `<servlet-class>sompackagepath.FetchServ</servlet-class>`

**EDIT**

As per your images, I can see you have declare `index.jsp` which will be accesible by giving url: `http://localhost:<port_number>/ACtxtbox/index.jsp`.

**Now you should note below points:**

1. As you are calling servlet using ajax call where you have given
   parameters as `fetch` in this line of code in you javascript 
   `xmlhttp.open("GET", "fetch", true);` hence it is now changing your
   url to `http://localhost:<port_number>/ACtxtbox/fetch`
2. your web.xml entry should be like this

```html
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>FetchServ</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.rishal.test.FetchServ</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>FetchServ</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/fetch</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

3. How come your url pattern is coming like
   `http://localhost:<port_number>/ACtxtbox/com.test.java/fetch` ? is
   it you have modified the web.xml entries. Please read the tutorials
   and google about web application,jsp,servlets and ajax calls. you
   should also note that you have to create your `servlet` class under
   some `package` as i have given in the web.xml entry
   `com.rishal.test` its package path and class is inside this package
   path.

```js
package com.rishal.test;
public class FetchServ extends HttpServlet {
----------------------
---------------------------
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and even though the URL points to the correct location of the servlet the response response status is still 404. Here are the screenshots; Please advise

Comment: where is your screenshots and what changes you have to done, update it in the question

Comment: I am now facing a new problem of Tomcat server crashing down whenever I do the servlet mapping in the web.xml. And even without the servlet mapping the browser is requesting  the correct URL but  of no use. Here are the links to the screenshots: https://imgur.com/qUzUkwl

Comment: Here's the link to the Tomcat error I am facing https://imgur.com/KyZfUom

Comment: @SanjayPatel are you saying that the AJAX is returning the suggestions for the name of the candidates ???

Comment: the links are not visible ,update them in your question. You will get option to attach image

Comment: I have updated the question with the screenshots. Please advise.

Comment: I have named the package to com.test.java but I am not able map the servlet in web.xml because it causes an error in the apache server. I have updated all the code snippets in the question, please advise;

Comment: do you see my suggestion , why you are declaring web.xml entries like this `<servlet-class>com.test.java/FetchServ</servlet-class>` this is not correct give proper package path. go through my web.xml entries and compare urs, also this not ur url `<url-pattern>/FetchServ</url-pattern>` your url pattern is `<url-pattern>/fetch</url-pattern>`.